# Failed to resolve com.dave morrissey.labs:subsampling-scale-image-view:3.5.0

Tags: android, image

I have to implement pinch to zoom functionality in a viewpager class and I have found that [subsampling-scale-image-view](https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view) library can be used to implement this functionality. I have added this library in the dependency but while syncing its showing `Failed to resolve compile 'com.davemorrissey.labs:subsampling-scale-image-view:3.5.0'`.Can someone give me some advice on how I can solve this issue?

Comment: How did you add the library as a dependency?

Comment: There is no space (" ") between `dave` and `morrissey`. Add this line to your dependencies block: `compile 'com.davemorrissey.labs:subsampling-scale-image-view:3.5.0'`. Then check if your Android Studio is connected to the Internet while syncing Gradle (assuming you're using AS and Gradle, of course).

Comment: I have added it from Project Structure as library dependency

Comment: Ya there is no space, I have added like this: compile 'com.davemorrissey.labs:subsampling-scale-image-view:3.5.0'

Answer (score 0):

I have downloaded the zip file of `subsampling-scale-image-view` and put it in the `libs` folder. Thats how I solved this issue.